2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Monero's Moderator election #2 has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:



Please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
